# Export Azure AD Group Member

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to export members of Azure IAM groups but getting an error of empty string. Below is my code

```
Set-AzContext -Subscription XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX 
$IAMGroups = Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.ObjectType-eq "Group"} | Select-Object DisplayName 
$IAMGroups 

$Result = Foreach ($IAMGroup in $IAMGroups) {Get-AzAdGroupMember -GroupDisplayName $IAMGroup} 
$Result | Export-Csv C:\audit-automation\Roles.csv
```

When I am trying to print $IAMGroups I get correct result however when I am trying to put each group to get members I get error of empty string as mentioned below. I have tried similar logic to export firewall rules in CSV and it seems to be working fine.

```
WARNING: This cmdlet is using API version beta which is under preview.
Get-AzAdGroupMember : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'GroupId' because it is an empty string.
At line:5 char:46
+ ... roup in $IAMGroups) {Get-AzAdGroupMember -GroupDisplayName $IAMGroup}
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Get-AzADGroupMember
```

Comment: $IAMGroups  is null. You need to find out why.  Best way of starting is to use Format-Table to get properties :  Get-AzRoleAssignment | Format-Table.

Comment: I think the problem is that you have "Select-Object DisplayName" so $IAMGroups does not contain the IDs and all other information. When you remove `| Select-Object DisplayName` from the second line of your script the script should run as expected

Comment: @jdweng when I try to print the $IAMGroups it does show the correct result.

Comment: Issue is either the Filter or the DisplayName.  Try one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output of `$IAMGroup`, you should see that the object has both a `Property` (**DisplayName**) and a `Value` (**Azure_Group01**).

```
$IAMGroup

DisplayName                                                      
-----------                                                      
Azure_Group01
```

Run `GetType()` on `$IAMGroup`, you'll see this is a `PSCustomObject` (a hashtable)

```
$iamgroup.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

When you call `Get-AzAdGroupMember`, you're passing in the object that contains both the `Property` and `Value`, but you only want to pass the `Value`.

**Solution**

Add the `ExpandProperty` switch to the `Select-Object` cmdlet.

```
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
```

Now see the output of `$IAMGroup`

```
$IAMGroup                                                                                                           
Azure_Group01
```

And see the type is a `String`

```
$IAMGroup.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: I did the changes you suggested but now the error has changed.


`Get-AzAdGroupMember : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'GroupId'. Cannot convert value to type System.String.
At line:5 char:53
+ ... roup in $IAMGroups) {Get-AzAdGroupMember -GroupDisplayName $IAMGroup}
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzADGroupMember], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Get-AzADGroupMember`